# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException Getting while integrating spring-data-cassandra with spring 3.0.5

Tags: spring, cassandra

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException Getting while integrating spring-data-cassandra-1.5.1 with spring 3.0.5, below the dependency,

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And My Configuration class,

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraUtil {

@Value("${bag.cassandra.keyspace}")     
private String KEYSPACE = "cart";

@Value("${bag.cassandra.cntactpoints}")     
private String CONTACTPOINTS = "localhost,127.0.0.1";

@Value("${bag.cassandra.port}")     
private int PORT = 9042;


@Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(CONTACTPOINTS);
    cluster.setPort(PORT);
    //logger.info("CassandraUtil :: cluster, CONTACTPOINTS: {}, PORT : 
     {}",CONTACTPOINTS,PORT);
    return cluster;
}

@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
    return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
}

@Bean
public CassandraConverter converter() {
    return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
}

@Bean
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {
    CassandraSessionFactoryBean cassandraSessionFactoryBean = new 
 CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    cassandraSessionFactoryBean.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
    cassandraSessionFactoryBean.setKeyspaceName(KEYSPACE);
    cassandraSessionFactoryBean.setConverter(converter());
    cassandraSessionFactoryBean.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
   // logger.info("CassandraUtil :: session, KEYSPACE: {}",KEYSPACE);
    return cassandraSessionFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
}

}
```

I understood because of version issue it is giving this exception, but tried almost all the version, please suggest better way to solve this.